# Factory System with 2 difrent Values

Tags: php, database, factory

I have created a Factory System. It works fine, but I have a problem with the VAT calculation.

I take a value from the database and it is stored in a array. So, if I take out the data with a For-Loop for make calculations, I only can use 1 value.

The value from the database can be 7 or 19.

At the release time the VAT would be fix on 7% but now I have new products that have 19% at VAT.

How can I calculate the price value with 7 or 19%?

It can have times that in the shopping cart I have both values (7 and 19%)

I take the Data from the Array that have the Values that i Need from the DB

```
foreach($contents as $data){
    $artikel_name = $data["name"];
    $artikel_price = $data["price"];
    $mwst = $data["mwst"]; //can be 7, 19 or both Values
    $kg = $data["kg"]; 
    $amount = $data["qty"];

    $html .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$artikel_name." ". $kg . "kg".'</td>
 <td style="text-align: center;">'.$amount.'</td> 
 <td style="text-align: center;">'.number_format($artikel_price, 2, ',', '').' Euro</td>    
 <td style="text-align: center;">'.$mwst.'</td> 
                <td style="text-align: center;">'.number_format($amount * $artikel_price, 2, ',', '').' Euro</td>
              </tr>';
$gesamtpreis += $amount * $artikel_price;


}
```

The value of mwst (VAT) is fix at the moment but the Problem ist that i need to make Calculation with 7, 19 or both

For know the Text appears at the moment if the Value of "umsazsteuer" is bigger than 0

How can i fix it ?

I use Google, I change the code for testing it